# Center Content XAML

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

How to center the element on XAML Windows 8.1? When set the margin after star application on full screen i see this:
[image]

```
<ProgressRing   Name="Load" 
                IsActive="True" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Margin="672,373,674,373" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Foreground="White"/>

<TextBlock  Margin="528,466,526,256" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Text="Caricamento..." 
            FontSize="50" 
            IsRightTapEnabled="False" 
            IsHoldingEnabled="False" 
            IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" 
            IsTapEnabled="False" 
            Foreground="White"/>
```

in programmer mode i see this:
[image]

Comment: horizontalALignment = "center"?

Comment: Use center Horizontal and Vertical alignments and remove the margin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, using `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` center. And not the margins.

```
<ProgressRing   Name="Load" 
                IsActive="True" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Foreground="White"/>

<TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Text="Caricamento..." 
            FontSize="50" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            IsRightTapEnabled="False" 
            IsHoldingEnabled="False" 
            IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" 
            IsTapEnabled="False" 
            Foreground="White"/>
```